# Access Form data disappears on a VBA requery

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form with a continuous subform that allows users to conduct keyword searches. I want to add VBA code that will reset the form to all of rows as if the form was reopened.

My code is:

```vb
Private Sub ResetForm_Click()
    Dim SQL As String

    SQL = "SELECT  Data_tbl.Category, " _
        & "Data_tbl.Component, " _
        & "Data_tbl.Source, Data_tbl.Criticality " _
        & "FROM Data_tbl ORDER BY Data_tbl.Category;"
        
     Me.subCategoryList.Form.RecordSource = SQL
     Me.subCategoryList.Form.Requery
End Sub
```

The menu bar at the bottom of the form shows that there are 536 records. However the requery 'erases' what is displayed. All of the rows are devoid of data.

What is strange is that other subs work using the same setup with the SQL variable.

It must be something subtle but I just cannot figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the `Recordsource` when form is first opened? Please post its SQL.

Comment: Do you really need ` Me.subCategoryList.Form.Requery` after `Me.subCategoryList.Form.RecordSource = SQL` ?

Comment: what they said, and for speeds sake try replacing everything in the click event with me.Filter = ""   ; me.requery  if the button is on the same form you are filtering me should refer to the form.  test by calling debug.print (me.name)

Comment: The Recordsource when the form opens is the same as above.

Comment: Here is a search function that limits the display of records to a subset:

Comment: Private Sub btnSearch_Click()
     Dim SQL As String

     SQL = "SELECT Data_tbl.Cat_ID, Data_tbl.Category, Data_tbl.Component, " _
       
         & "Data_tbl.Criticality] FROM Data_tbl " _
         & "WHERE Category  LIKE '*" & Me.txtKeywords & "*' " _
         & " OR   Component LIKE '*" & Me.txtKeywords & "*' " 
       
     SQL = SQL & "ORDER BY Data_tbl.Category"
         
     Me.subCategoryList.Form.RecordSource = SQL
     Me.subCategoryList.Form.Requery

End Sub

Comment: @mazoula I tried what you suggested and replaced everything in the click event. But that didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Hy,

Is the button on your subform ?
I would try to add the code bellow assuming that the button is on your subform.

```
Me.RecordSource = "Select * from Data_tbl order by Category Desc"

Me.Requery
```

Comment: [Access 2013]  
Private Sub ResetForm_Click()  

    Dim SQL As String  
   
    SQL = "SELECT  * FROM Controller_Data_tbl;"  
        
    Me.subCategoryList.Form.RecordSource = SQL  
       
    Me.Requery  
      
End Sub

Comment: Hy Dave, could you mark this as an anwser ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be with the "ORDER BY" clause.  If I add DESC at the end, the requery works.  In some cases, taking the default to ASC clears the for with no rows filled in. I don't understand why ascending won't work but at least I have a work around.